# SQL-SERVER Quarter Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-function

I've written an SQL function to turn an INT (month value) into a VARCHAR representing the Quarter of the year.

My code is as follows.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [sf_Quarters] (@DATE date)
Returns VARCHAR(4)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @QUARTER VARCHAR(4) = '';
 DECLARE @DATEMONTH INT = DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE);

SELECT @QUARTER =
 CASE
     WHEN @DATEMONTH > 3 AND  @DATEMONTH < 7 THEN 'Q1'
     WHEN @DATEMONTH > 6 AND  @DATEMONTH < 10 THEN 'Q2'
     WHEN @DATEMONTH > 9 AND  @DATEMONTH <= 12 THEN 'Q3'
     WHEN @DATEMONTH > 0 AND  @DATEMONTH < 4 THEN 'Q4'
     ELSE NULL
 END
 RETURN @QUARTER
END
```

For some reason when I pass this function a valid date object (in my testcase) I only get the single char 'Q' back out.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE = '20090405'
DECLARE @Qat VARCHAR

EXEC @Qat = sf_Quarters @DATE

SELECT @Qat
```

I realise I'm probably doing something daft thats breaking it. I just cant understand why it's only returning the first of the CHARS.

I have also substituted my fixed date string with the function (Current_Timestamp) and got the same result.

Comment: Select @Qat = dbo.sf_Quarters(@DATE)

Comment: DECLARE @Qat VARCHAR -- I remember it declares only one character and that is why you are getting only 'Q'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the second part where you are calling the function -

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE = '20090405'
DECLARE @Qat VARCHAR  -- change it to VARCHAR(4)
--varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
--When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1
EXEC @Qat = sf_Quarters @DATE

SELECT @Qat
```

**Note:** Follow the way Gordon suggested to invoke a function

Comment: Cheers for the help, I knew it would be something incredibly silly. Changing the @Qat Declaration fixed it.

Comment: I don't think it's right because he has a function and you do not execute functions, just select it's value if it's scalar one or just select from a function if it's tvf.

Answer (score 2):

It seems so much simpler to do:

```
select 'Q' + datename(quarter, dateadd(month, -3, @date))
```

As for your question, the way to call a function is using `SELECT`:

```
SELECT @Qat = sf_Quarters(@DATE);
```

You are calling the function as if it were a stored procedure.  I'm surprised that works at all.

Comment: Yeah, I attempted your solution first, it doesn't actually fire this way, I even took out the declaration (WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER) and tried again. I kept getting an error regarding the function not being recognised.
@Abhishek's answer worked though. 

Thank you btw I appreciate the help.